# iOS SIGABRT in Main.m (backtrace provided)

Tags: ios, sigabrt, backtrace

Getting the SIGABRT error in main.m.  I have listed the back trace form the console to see if someonbe could point me in the right direction.

```
#0  0x94d77c5a in __kill ()
#1  0x94d77c4c in kill$UNIX2003 ()
#2  0x94e0a5a5 in raise ()
#3  0x94e206e4 in abort ()
#4  0x94d9cb1b in _Unwind_Resume ()
#5  0x012abe39 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#6  0x012abccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#7  0x002c12a7 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#8  0x002c2a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#9  0x000028d9 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffec90) at /      Users/user-   
    name/Desktop/ProjectFive/ProjectFive/ProjectFive/main.m:20
#10 0x00002825 in start ()
```

This is the core dump information that I have been able to copy.  The SIGABRT happens right at the autorelease statement in my main.m

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,      
NSStringFromClass([ProjectFiveAppDelegate class]));
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
```

...

```
0x002c297f  <+0891>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x002c2982  <+0894>  call   0x75d8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x002c2987  <+0899>  mov    %eax,%esi
0x002c2989  <+0901>  mov    0x69940e(%edi),%eax
0x002c298f  <+0907>  mov    0x68db46(%edi),%ecx
0x002c2995  <+0913>  lea    0x525009(%edi),%edx
0x002c299b  <+0919>  mov    %edx,0x8(%esp)
0x002c299f  <+0923>  mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
0x002c29a3  <+0927>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x002c29a6  <+0930>  call   0x75d8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x002c29ab  <+0935>  mov    0x68df86(%edi),%ecx
0x002c29b1  <+0941>  mov    %ebx,0x18(%esp)
0x002c29b5  <+0945>  lea    0x6a6c56(%edi),%edx
0x002c29bb  <+0951>  mov    %edx,0x14(%esp)
0x002c29bf  <+0955>  mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
0x002c29c3  <+0959>  mov    %esi,0x8(%esp)
0x002c29c7  <+0963>  mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
0x002c29cb  <+0967>  mov    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
0x002c29ce  <+0970>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x002c29d1  <+0973>  movl   $0x641,0x10(%esp)
0x002c29d9  <+0981>  call   0x75d8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x002c29de  <+0986>  mov    0x699476(%edi),%eax
0x002c29e4  <+0992>  mov    0x68db72(%edi),%ecx
0x002c29ea  <+0998>  mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
0x002c29ee  <+1002>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x002c29f1  <+1005>  call   0x75d8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x002c29f6  <+1010>  mov    0x68df92(%edi),%ecx
0x002c29fc  <+1016>  mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
0x002c2a00  <+1020>  mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
0x002c2a04  <+1024>  mov    -0x10(%ebp),%esi
0x002c2a07  <+1027>  mov    %esi,(%esp)
0x002c2a0a  <+1030>  call   0x75d8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x002c2a0f  <+1035>  mov    0x6d0fbe(%edi),%ebx
0x002c2a15  <+1041>  test   %al,%al
0x002c2a17  <+1043>  je     0x2c2a2c <UIApplicationMain+1064>
0x002c2a19  <+1045>  mov    0x68dbb6(%edi),%eax
0x002c2a1f  <+1051>  mov    %ebx,0x8(%esp)
0x002c2a23  <+1055>  mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x002c2a27  <+1059>  mov    %ebx,(%esp)
0x002c2a2a  <+1062>  jmp    0x2c2a69 <UIApplicationMain+1125>
0x002c2a2c  <+1064>  mov    0x68dc0a(%edi),%eax
0x002c2a32  <+1070>  mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x002c2a36  <+1074>  mov    %esi,(%esp)
0x002c2a39  <+1077>  call   0x75d8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x002c2a3e  <+1082>  mov    0x68dcba(%edi),%ecx
0x002c2a44  <+1088>  mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
0x002c2a48  <+1092>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x002c2a4b  <+1095>  call   0x75d8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x002c2a50  <+1100>  mov    0x68df96(%edi),%ecx
0x002c2a56  <+1106>  mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
0x002c2a5a  <+1110>  mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
0x002c2a5e  <+1114>  mov    %ebx,(%esp)
0x002c2a61  <+1117>  movl   $0x1,0xc(%esp)
0x002c2a69  <+1125>  call   0x75d8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x002c2a6e  <+1130>  mov    0x68db22(%edi),%eax
0x002c2a74  <+1136>  mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x002c2a78  <+1140>  mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
0x002c2a7b  <+1143>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x002c2a7e  <+1146>  call   0x75d8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x002c2a83  <+1151>  mov    0x6d0fbe(%edi),%eax
0x002c2a89  <+1157>  mov    0x68df9a(%edi),%ecx
0x002c2a8f  <+1163>  mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
0x002c2a93  <+1167>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x002c2a96  <+1170>  call   0x75d8b2 <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
0x002c2a9b  <+1175>  xor    %eax,%eax
0x002c2a9d  <+1177>  add    $0x2c,%esp
0x002c2aa0  <+1180>  pop    %esi
0x002c2aa1  <+1181>  pop    %edi
0x002c2aa2  <+1182>  pop    %ebx
0x002c2aa3  <+1183>  pop    %ebp
0x002c2aa4  <+1184>  ret
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this backtrace isn't very helpful.  We're going to need the code that is having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely the result of an uncaught exception.  You should try to use one of the following to track the problem down:

1. analysis of the source which was executing close to the failure
2. a source debugger (set it to break on exception throws)
3. a static checker like Coverity Static Analysis, Clang Static Analyzer, or just crank up the compiler warnings
4. a dynamic checker like Electric Fence, Klee or `valgrind` (helgrind/memcheck)

Comment: The actual error happens at the Autoreleasepool statement.  The program never executes beyond that.

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint in the Xcode 4 breakpoint navigator. I'll wager that it breaks on your code and not in main.m.

Comment: Mark, I went to the breakpoint navigator and selected "break on all exceptions".  THe line in which the breakpoint stopped was the following:

      int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ProjectFiveAppDelegate class]));